# Using external babel configuration breaks node/react app - internal server error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, next.js

Does anyone have any clue why a babel config file would be loaded on `npm run dev` and why it would start flagging perfectly fine parts of my code?

I have a feeling it has something to do with Next.js. My package.json (that Im testing with) for reference:

```
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "@svgr/cli": "^4.2.0",
  "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
  "jest": "^24.8.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
}
```

My goal is to have an app that runs both `npm run dev` and `npm test` and not one or the other. At the moment, if I remove all my babel config files (needed to run `jest`), my web app will boot up perfectly fine. And vice versa. Honestly I don't think I need or want any babel config files to be active when I start running the server, but I need them to run `jest`.

So... either there is a way to disable babel from certain package.json scripts or otherwise get `jest` tests to work without breaking the core functionality of the app?

edit-i fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//.babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel"
    ]
  ]
}
```